# Buttons are not appearing in a basic Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

As shown in image no text of "Hello world" and floating action button appear.

[image]

I changed my **styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="io.sentry.sentry_android_example.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="io.sentry.sentry_android_example.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As per many comments, I have updated my activity_main.xml, content_main.xml styles.xml
But in design layout, I am still not able to see the buttons and text

> And now I am getting errors
>   1)Render problem Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in the current theme
>   2)Render problem Couldn't resolve resource @dimen/activity_horizontal_margin
>   3)Missing Styles
>   4)Failed to instantiate one or more class

Comment: post `main_activity.xml`

Comment: Please post main activity and content xmls

Comment: I am posting my XML please have some patience

Comment: @John Joe posted main_activity.xml

Comment: don't post your code as image, paste your code instead.

Comment: @John Joe I am unable to post as it exceeds line define by stack overflow and getting varities of error not indented and so on

Comment: https://pastebin.com/beWd3e9q

Comment: activity_main.xml:- https://pastebin.com/BwstCVb4

Comment: which file actually having problems ?

Comment: I am getting now Render problem,Missing Style, Failed to instantiate one or more class. And I am still no getting any buttons or "Hello world " on layout

Comment: which file you are you referring to ? There are two files

Comment: I am getting that Render problem etc in activity_main.xml that is the file I am referring

Comment: please post content_main.xml

Comment: Pls, check your `main_activity.xml`. There's no starting tag for `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani I edited see the question

Comment: @JohnJoe I edited it see the question

Comment: @KD. answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

In the right corner of the screen shot it shows read mark that means you have an error should have to be fixed so please click the read mark and check the error or please post your xml so that i can help you more.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: Render problem Failed to find style 'floatingActionButtonStyle' in current theme                                                                                           
 Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references. And Failed to instantiate class are getting error

Answer (score 0):

This is my style and it works fine please check it out

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Here is my screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I changed and I am getting error                                                                        Render problem Failed to find style 'floatingActionButtonStyle' in current theme Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout? Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references. And Failed to instantiate class are getting error

Answer (score 0):

There are something wrong in `styles.xml`. Use this instead, which is default

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

You must be accidentally deleted the `resources` tag.

And for below issue

> Render problem Couldn't resolve resource
>   @dimen/activity_horizontal_margin

Go to `values --> dimens.xml`, and add below line in `resources` tag

```
 <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">15dp</dimen>
```

Hope this helped.